# How to make a web GUI for Python 3 (Javascript communications)?

Tags: javascript, python, user-interface, python-3.x, web

I've made a program in Python 2.7 with a wxWidgets GUI. Now, I want to improve it by making a web GUI, make it multi-platform and port it in Python 3.4. For this purpose, I have to make Javascript and Python communicate (i.e : I want my Python to react on some event on the page and I want my page to react on some Python actions).

I don't really know how to do it, and I don't even know if it's possible.
I've find some libraries, but some are just for Python 2 (pyjamas), and some don't provide what I search, or I don't search enough ^^ (web2py, turbogear, cherrypy).

I would like to find a complete library that ease this communication, and that is rather known and supported, with a compete documentation.

Maybe, there are other ways to do such a web GUI, but I don't find them.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is a single page application.

I would suggest to wrap your python code in a RESTful Api using a python web framework like Flask. This would isolate your python code from the presentation layer.

You could then write the UI in html and javascript and use AJAX to call your python api from javascript.

Comment: I've seen the method with AJAX to call Python, but I don't really understand how to dynamically change my page's elements from my Python.

Comment: What do you mean dinamically? Can you give an example?

Comment: For example I click on a button that triggers Python operations, and a Python function change the color of an element depending on the result of the operations.

Comment: In this case when you click the button it will trigger the javascript code to make an ajax request to python and python will reply to the request with the color and then you will change the color with javascript

Comment: I think I don't give a good example... The Python doesn't always respond to Javascript. Mostly, it triggers itself to push events to GUI, without any call of Javascript.

Comment: In that case consider using websockets and/or socket.io to create a bi-directional connection.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will search in that way. Do you have any good and complete library to do such a thing ?

Comment: Its a matter of preference. Any good python webframework should have extensions for websockets and helpers to write RESTful apis. For small projects I personally prefer Flask and would also use the extesion Flask-socketio https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. I recently came across a good article that involves wraping python code in a RESTful api and creating a web ui (http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/12/08/adding-web-interface-image-search-engine-flask/)